# What does `extraHeight` property do on `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am implementing `react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view` in my react-native app, and I have a quick question about the `extraHeight` property, which you can assign a number to. In the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) this property is described like so:

> Adds an extra offset when focusing the TextInputs.

My implementation looks like this:

```
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView
    enableAutomaticScroll
    enableOnAndroid
    keyboardOpeningTime={0}
    extraHeight={600}
    style={{
      ...config.defaultStyles.layout.container,
      backgroundColor: config.defaultStyles.colors.background,
      padding: 0,
    }}
  >{this.props.children}
  </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

My question is around what this specifically means. What is the offset here on `extraHeight`, and what does that change, in terms of the user experience? I've tried adjusting the value but I'm not clear on what it is doing exactly.

Answer (score 0):

this will raise your input a little higher. if KeyboardAwareScrollView is used and still something is not visible, you use extraHeight to position the scroll a little further.